# Nodejs synchronously read a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I've this piece of code

```
var fs = require('fs');
var csv = require('fast-csv');
const dishTypes = [];

        fs.createReadStream('dishtypes_id.csv')
            .pipe(csv())

            .on('data', function (data) {
                dishTypes.push(data)
            })
            .on('end', function (data) {
                console.log("END", data)

            })



console.log("DISHTYPES",dishTypes)
```

Output is this

```
DISHTYPES []
END 3839
```

I can imagine what's going on here. But I can't tackle it. **dishTypes** array should populate with 3839 objects. But right now it's empty. Because this **fast-csv** thing works in **async** way. How do I tackle that? I mean console.log should run after the end function.

Comment: Just move the `console.log` of the array inside the `end` event callback.

Comment: fast-csv is not async, but fs.createReadStream is.